# Put maxDataPoints in grafana datasource

Tags: javascript, dashboard, grafana

I am using grafana 5.1.4. I build a custom datasource. But the property maxDataPoints no are show in datasource config.

This is my file structure:

[image]

My code in query.options.html:

```
<section class="grafana-metric-options">
<div class="gf-form">
</div>
<div class="gf-form-inline">
    <div class="gf-form max-width-15">
        <span class="gf-form-label">Max data points</span>
        <input type="text"
               class="gf-form-input"
               ng-model="ctrl.panelCtrl.panel.maxDataPoints"
               bs-tooltip="'Override max data points, automatically set to graph width in pixels.'"
               data-placement="right"
               ng-model-onblur ng-change="ctrl.panelCtrl.refresh()"
               spellcheck='false'
               placeholder="auto">
        </input>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my pluging.json:

```
"queryOptions": {
   "maxDataPoints": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** Can I access the property values of `plugin.json`? If so how can I access the `maxDataPoints` property from my controller?

**A:** You can only access **some** of the property values in the `plugin.json`. These values can be found in the `PluginMeta` class, an instance of it can be found in the`instanceSettings.meta` variable of the `Datasource` class. [Example](https://github.com/grafana/simple-json-datasource/blob/master/src/datasource.js#L5)

Unfortunately the `maxDataPoints` property is **not** one of those property which you can have access to.

If you have a valid `use-case` you can try putting in a pull request to ask the Grafana team to expose it for you.

This [piece of Grafana server cod](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/blob/master/pkg/plugins/models.go)e determines what is made available to the client from all `plugin.json`. And yes, if you want to expose `maxDataPoint` property, you'll have to extend that code.